# How to get the total power of the signal from sound pressure levels?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I have the Sound Pressure Levels (SPL(f)) of noise signals in the frequency domain. I need to get the total acoustic power of the signal between a range of frequencies.
Initially, I compute the Power Spectral Density (PSD(f)) from SPL(f) using the following equation:
[image]

I could invert this equation where I get PSD(f) in terms of Pascal^2 at every unit freq.
How do I proceed from here?

Since Intensity of noise (Watt/m^2) is given by P^2/(density*speed of sound). Should I compute that to get the PSD(f) in terms of Watt/m^2 and then integrate over the frequency?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could invert this equation where I get PSD(f) in terms of Pascal^2 at every unit freq.

Correct.

> How do I proceed from here?

The intensity of the sound field is given as

$$I = p\cdot v$$

where $p$ is the pressure (in Pa) and $v$ the particle velocity (in m/s). If your measurement has been done in air reasonably far away from any boundary, you can assume the velocity and pressure are in phase with each other and hence related by the acoustic free field impedance of air $Z_A = 420 kg/(s\cdot m^2)$

And hence we get

$$I = \frac{p^2}{Z_A}$$

Now we are stuck. You have the Intensity at one location of the sound field, but the Total Acoustic Power is an integral quantity over the entire sound field. Without any additional assumptions about the shape of the sound field, we cannot proceed. Possible options here are

1. Omnidirectional sound in a free field ($4\pi$ or $2\pi$) measured in the far field. In this case you can assume a spherical wave which you can spatially integrate over a sphere around the source at the distance where the measurement was taken.
2. Measurement was taken with a steady state signal in a diffuse sound field, reasonably far away from the source and any boundaries and the reverberation time of the space is known. You can use the steady state equations for a diffuse sound field, but note that the reverb time is almost always significantly dependent on frequency so you need to split it into appropriate bands
3. Take measurements in free field on a spatially "dense enough" spatial grid filly enclosing the source. Just spatially integrate the intensity to get the power.

> then integrate over the frequency

Yes. Once you have converted things into actual $W/Hz$ you can simply integrate over the frequency range of interest. Note that there are potentially other frequency dependent variables (such as reverb time) which would also have to go into that integral.

Comment: Thank you very much!

To clarify, I am dealing with underwater noise signals so the impedance is 1.5*10^6 kg/(m^2s)
So the equation to get intensity at every frequency at that particular point in the field becomes the following:
 I(f) = PSF(f)/1.5^10^6 [Watt/m^2Hz]

Subsequently, I will get the total intensity between two freq at that one point by integration which will be in Watt/m^2.

Comment: I have one more question  - Will the SPL and spectral density in dB of a sound pressure signal give me the same plot? SPL = 10log (P/Po)^2 whereas spectral density in dB is again 10log(PSD/Po^2). But one is in dB re 1 μPa and the other dB re 1 μPa^2/Hz. I am confused. Thank you for your time and support!

Comment: That depends a bit on exactly the PSD and/or the pressure signals are derived and processed. If you do things with numbers inside a computer, you have to use the Discrete Fourier Transform (not the Continuous Fourier Transform) and units do indeed work differently for the DFT.